# How to display HTML from input box

Tags: forms, submit, innerhtml, string-interpolation

I'm trying to display a message that appears after the user has input some details into input boxes. Once they put in the info in the input boxes, the page should add the info to the multi-line text and then display the entire message on the webpage with the new info included. This code I have only displays the message without the input.

Here, I'm simply having the user put in the text in the box, then I tried to "parse" the input's value by giving it a variable name with a value within the code so it can be added as a property to the "libs" object. I have more to the message, but I can't even get this one sentence to process correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Madder Libs</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="input">

        <form>  
            <p>
                <h4>Piece of clothing:</h4><input id="cloth" type="text" value=" " />
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>

        <script>
            let clothes = document.getElementById('cloth').value;
            let libs = {
                a: clothes,
                /*b: firstBodyPart,
                c: secondBodyPart,
                d: verbOne,
                e: thirdBodyPart,
                f: verbTwo,
                g: firstNoun,
                h: secondNoun,
                i: verbThree,*/
                };

            let showThis = function()
            {
                let display = function(message)
                {
                    let sayThis = `I wear a ${message.a} on sundays.`;
                    return sayThis;
                }

                document.getElementById('madlibs').innerHTML += "<br/>" + display(libs);
            }

        </script>

    <div id="madlibs">

        <button type="submit" onclick="showThis()">Show Message</button>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I want my message to be displayed including whatever the user put in the text box

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by addressing why your sentence does not work. It is simply a matter of timing or in other words when things get executed. In your code (which isn't very well structured but onto that later) you execute

`let clothes = document.getElementById('cloth').value;`

at the very beginning of the script. In this case you are not obtaining some form of reference that would allow you to read the value at later stage but the actual value at the time. Since your `input` field has `value` attribute set to empty string, this is all you will ever get no matter how many times you execute the function later.

In order to get value of the input at the time of calling your method **you would have to move it into the function itself**.

But as I mentioned earlier your code is overall structured poorly so allow me to provide a few suggestions.

1. `button` of type submit by default executes submission of the form if placed within the form; you are not taking advantage of that (this has benefits such ability to submit form with "Enter" key e.g.
2. placing `<script>` in the middle of your document is poor choice as it blocks rendering of the rest of the document. Best options are to place it either within `<head>` when used with `defer` attribute or at the end of the document just before closing `</body>` tag.
3. Nesting your function within each other has not benefit here. You can easily define them independently and call one within the other if needed.
4. heading element `<h4>` cannot appear within `<p>` tag

**Example**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Madder Libs</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/" onsubmit="return showThis()">
      <div>
        <label for="cloth">Piece of clothing:</label>
        <input id="cloth" type="text" value="" />
      </div>
      <div id="madlibs"></div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit">Show Message</button>
      </div>
    </form>

    <script>
      // let's get references to our elements, so we don't have to
      // do it multiple times
      let clothes = document.getElementById('cloth');
      let madlibs = document.getElementById('madlibs');

      // let's define our functions
      function display(message) {
        let sayThis = `I wear a ${message.a} on sundays.`;
        return sayThis;
      }

      function showThis() {
        const clothesValue = clothes.value;
        let libs = {
            a: clothesValue,
            /*b: firstBodyPart,
            c: secondBodyPart,
            d: verbOne,
            e: thirdBodyPart,
            f: verbTwo,
            g: firstNoun,
            h: secondNoun,
            i: verbThree,*/
        };
        madlibs.innerHTML += "<br/>" + display(libs);
        return false;
      }
    </script>
</body>
```